# Json.Net error in XCODE - System.Reflection.Emit

Tags: ios, json, xcode, unity-game-engine, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON file on iOS and have used Json.Net for that. But when app runs in XCODE simulator it gives me error about System.Reflection.Emit, it seems that XCODE not allows to use that library in app.
I can guess that reflection is using when it tries to put the values in specified type's fields. 
Can I avoid that? Instead of that I want to create something like JSONObject, a dictionary with keys and fields. 
I guess this approach will allow me to deserialize JSON correctly without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using miniJSON (my current choice) or JsonFX for full support with Unity3D platforms.
As for iOS, majority of Unity3D mobile devs recommend JsonFX for larger chunks of data.

**miniJSON:** [@ GitHub](https://raw.github.com/gist/1411710/MiniJSON.cs)

**JsonFX:** [@ Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/TowerOfBricks/jsonfx-for-unity3d/src/d3108fa8ee9f9e0f304269f16db214610f56a7b5/JsonFx/JsonFx.Json/bin/Release/?at=default)

**Example of serialization with JsonFX** (from raybarrera.com blog*):

```
public string fileName;
public Sandwich sandwich;

private string PATH;

private void Start() {
    PATH = Application.dataPath + "/../testData/";
}
private void OnGUI()   {
    if (GUILayout.Button("SAVE")){
        SerializeAndSave();
    }
}

private void SerializeAndSave() {
    string data = JsonWriter.Serialize(sandwich);
    if(!Directory.Exists(PATH)){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(PATH);
    }
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(PATH + fileName + ".txt");
    streamWriter.Write(data);
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

*http://www.raybarrera.com/2014/05/18/json-deserialization-using-unity-and-jsonfx/

Comment: i have already tried miniJSON and JsonFX but they can't deserialize next JSON file http://pastebin.com/MDKSPxyR and here is JSON which I got after serializing specified object to string http://pastebin.com/AD7qE0GN. The structures seems identical, but both libraries can't deserialize first JSON file.

Comment: Can you please share class you're serializing? Can't test it without it.

Comment: I use List of ChapterModel, ChapterModel contains list of PageModel, here is these two classes http://pastebin.com/ajQP97WN

Comment: I've answered in your second relevant question. If it solves your problem, please mark as answered to close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `Newtonsoft.Json` version 11.0.2 for **serialization** (didn't test deserialization) with IL2CPP and iOS with the following **link.xml**:

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="System">
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ArrayConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ByteConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CharConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CollectionConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ComponentConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CultureInfoConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DecimalConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int16Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int64Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.SByteConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.SingleConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.StringConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.TimeSpanConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt16Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt32Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt64Converter" preserve="all"/>
    </assembly>

    <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.name?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-2.0-->
    <assembly fullname="System.Core">
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.*" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression" preserve="all"/>
    </assembly>
    <assembly fullname="System.Linq.Expressions">
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.*" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression" preserve="all"/>
    </assembly>
    <assembly fullname="netstandard">
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.*" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression" preserve="all"/>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

You might get away removing some of those though. The types I used to serialize are part of the .NET SDK for Sentry. [source is here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/).

Comment: Thanks to Bruno's answer, we were able to overcome problems in our build that occurred only when we targetted iOS. The exception and stack trace can be hard to interpret and misleading, as we were getting a JsonSerializationException citing an error in setting a member of the class the JSON string was being deserialized to. After experiments where we failed to even serialize a simple class, we started investing system and compatibility problems and came across this answer. Upon closer inspection of the stack trace, we could see some references to constructor errors in LINQ